# Wordpress post grid sort by custom field only when it has value

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, custom-fields

I have a custom field for posts named "sort by date". I want to be able to sort my custom grid by post create date *unless* this custom "sort by date" field has a value... in other words, if the custom field has a value I want wordpress to take that date and leverage it for sorting purposes.

Right now I have my variables defined as

```
$fields['customDate'] = get_field('updated_date', $post->ID);
    
    if (!empty($fields['customDate'])) {
            $fields['orderDate'] = $fields['customDate'];
        } else {
        $fields['orderDate'] = get_the_date('Ymd', $post);
    }
```

For displaying the dates on the page this works fine
`<?php echo date('F j, Y', strtotime($fields['orderDate']));?>`

For my query I have

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'numberposts' => $numberposts,
            'tax_query' => $taxQueries,
            'post__not_in' => $exclusions,
            
            'orderby' => array(
                'orderDate' => 'DESC'
            )
            ));
```

However, I do realize that by not having values in my custom field for all other posts in the database this isn't going to work.

Is there a way to sort by combining the two fields (create date and the custom field) so that *if the custom field has value* use it for sorting, if not use the post create date?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I answered your question. In general its much better practice to save dates in mysql format and convert it when displaying. can do better sorting etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to grab the posts then sort them on your own and then feed that to the query via the `post__in` parameter

Define the sorting function

```
function my_sort($a,$b){
    $t1 = strtotime($a['date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['date']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}
```

Get all post IDs

```
$post_ids = get_posts(array(
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'numberposts' => $numberposts,
    'tax_query' => $taxQueries,
    'post__not_in' => $exclusions,
));
```

Set the array for later use

```
$get_posts = $post_ids = array();
```

Loop through the ids and check if the meta value is set and store in new array

```
foreach($post_ids as $id){
    $updated_date = get_field('updated_date', $id);
    $date = $updated_date ? $updated_date : get_the_date('Ymd', $id);
    $get_posts[] = array('id' => $id, 'date' => $date );
}
```

Sort the new post array

```
usort($get_posts, 'my_sort');
```

Loop through the sorted array and get the ids

```
foreach($get_posts as $p ){
    $post_ids[] = $p['id'];
}
```

And finally get the posts from the sorted array ordered by our sort

```
$posts = get_post(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post__in'  => $post_ids,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby'=> 'post__in',
));
```